# UBER api, can I retrieve driver fare for each ride (for a driver's utility)?

Tags: driver, uber-api, fare

I am building a small utility for uber drivers.  Currently when they drop off a passenger and eventually get the resulting fare processed and returned to them, I have them manually enter it into the utility.  Is there a way to 'catch' this information programmatically and automatically populate my utility when this becomes available to the partner application?

Answer (score 1):

We don't currently make this kind of data generally available via the API. But thanks for your interest and the question, it helps us to understand what the community is looking for so we can prioritize what gets built and released next.

Keep an eye on the [Uber Developers blog](https://medium.com/uber-developers) for news around upcoming APIs.